# Accessing a file path from an HTML input in Tauri

Tags: javascript, electron, tauri

I have an app that I'm converting from Electron to Tauri. It's pretty plain, just an HTML file with some client side JS in it. One of the things that it does is when you click a button, it opens a file dialog, and it saves the path of that file.

In Electron, it exposes the path, but Tauri doesn't seem to. Any tips on how I can get that file path in the JS?

My HTML:

`<input type="file" accept=".pdf" id="file" />`

My JS:

```
document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", () => {
    pathUrl = document.getElementById("file").files[0].path;
    savePath();
});
```

Again, this works just fine in Electron, but I'm not sure how to Tauri-ify this.

I added the dialog thing to the allowlist:

```
"dialog": {
  "open": true
}
```

But I'm not sure if I'm on the right track!

Comment: Do you have to rely on the HTML `file` input? If not, you could handle this via [Tauri's `dialog` API](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/dialog#open) in JavaScript by calling `dialog.open()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why do you need the path?
Wouldn't the content work?
Also have you considered using URL blob instead?

Comment: I need the path to store a location over time!